# Trying to understand the reference cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, retain-cycle

I was reading Apple's documentation about Objective-C's reference cycles and then I tried to create one, but I can't quite understand its behaviour. Here what I have: there are two classes `XYZPerson` and `XYZPersonSpouse`.
They have properties for their first name, last name and properties of type `NSString` called `spouseName`. In `main` I set `spouseName` properties of both classes to each others name like this (in `init` of both classes I call their `designated initializers`, which set their first names and last names):

```
 XYZPerson *person = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];
 XYZPersonSpouse *spouseOfXYZPerson = [[XYZPersonSpouse alloc] init];


 spouseOfXYZPerson.spouseName = person.firstName;
 person.spouseName = spouseOfXYZPerson.firstName;
```

I also override `dealloc` method of both classes to print some text on the console. Now, because I don't use `weak` or `unsafe_unretained`, while defining properties `spouseName` on both classes, I assume that by the code above I created a strong reference cycle. However, when later I assign another `NSString` as a name of `XYZPerson` class's instance `person` like this:

```
 person.spouseName = @"Julia";
```

(but even without this) and run my project, I keep seeing the message for the `dealloc` method of `XYZPersonSpouse` class (and for `XYZPerson`, too).

Shouldn't the classes still not be kept because of the reference cycle? 
If you could explain what is going on here, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: FYI - The modern (post ARC) term is "reference cycle", not "retain cycle".

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you for the observation, I will change the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't seeing a reference/retain cycle because this isn't a reference cycle.

In your example, `person` and `spouseOfPerson` are objects with strong pointers to their string properties `firstName` and `spouseName`. **These person objects don't have strong pointers to each other, they have strong pointers to the strings.** Since the strings don't have strong references to the person objects, no cycle is created.

If you want to create a reference cycle, you need the objects themselves to have strong pointers to each other. To do that, you will want to declare the following properties:

```
XYZPerson
@property (nonatomic, strong) XYZPersonSpouse *spouse

XYZPersonSpouse
@property (nonatomic, strong) XYZPerson *spouse
```

If you then do the following instead of the two lines where you set the names, you will have a reference cycle.

```
spouseOfXYZPerson.spouse = person;
person.spouse = spouseOfXYZPerson;
```

To break the reference cycle, change either `spouse` property to `weak`.

Comment: thank you so much for making it clear. Now I understand it!